# Error import xml file pwct 9.61

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I tried to import a xml file (which was export from another informatica client) with the command objectimport but it gives me the following error :

`unable to write text to the repository because the data was too long`

Do you know how can I fix this issue ?

Fix : apparently it's a well-known problem when importing a xml. I just deleted the description that was too long and added them back afterwards and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your column widths in XML editor.